# Why is $\dfrac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}\neq n^k$?

Tags: combinatorics

The general formula for the number of unordered samples of size k with replacement from n elements is $\binom{n+k−1}{k}$. If we put in order it, then, the number will be $\binom{n+k−1}{k}\times k!=\dfrac{(n+k-1)!}{k!(n-1)!}\times k!$.

But, the general formula for the number of ordered samples of size k with replacement from n elements is $n^k$.

But, $\dfrac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}\neq n^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is you can't just multiply by $k!$ to include the order of the elements.

If all $k$ elements are different, you can.

Eg, $(1,2,3)$ has $3!=6$ orderings.

It becomes a problem when not all elements are different. Take for example the elements $(1,1,2)$.

Permutating them gives only $3$ orderings: $(1,1,2)$, $(1,2,1)$ and $(2,1,1)$.

As you can see, the number of different permutations depends on how much elements are the same. The right factor depends on every single case: If there is $a$ times element $1$, $b$ times $2$, $c$ times $3$, etc... you'll have to multiply by $\frac{k!}{a!\cdot b!\cdot c!\cdots}$ to make sure you don't count any permutation twice.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir! So, do you mean that $\dfrac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!a!b!c!\dots}= n^k$ ?

Comment: No, it's not that simple. The factor $\frac{k!}{a!\cdot b!\cdot c!\cdots}$ differs from choice to choice. E.g, consider the set $\{1,2,3\}$. The possible (unordered) selections of $3$ elements are $(1,1,1)$, $(1,1,2)$, $(1,2,2)$, $(2,2,2)$, $(1,1,3)$, etc... Every selection needs another factor. The selection $(1,1,1)$ needs a factor $\frac{3!}{3!\cdot0!\cdot0!}$ ($a=3$, $b=0$, $c=0$). The choice $(1,1,2)$ needs a factor $\frac{3!}{2!\cdot1!\cdot0!}$. The choice $(1,2,3)$ will have to be multiplied by $\frac{3!}{1!\cdot1!\cdot1!}$. There isn't really another nice formula like $n^k$.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, Sir! How clearly you can explain! Now I will not be confused.

Comment: You could write $$\sum_{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=k}\frac{k!}{a_1!\cdot a_2!\cdots a_n!}.$$ The sum goes through all ordered tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ whose sum is $k$ and $a_1,a_2,\ldots\geq0$. (Compare this to the $a,b,c$ in the previous examples: $a=a_1$, $b=a_2$, $c=a_3$.) However, this formula is not as nice as $n^k$, and the factor $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}$ completely disappears.

Comment: Note that the factor $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}$ is still reflected in the number of terms of the summation: There are exactly $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}$ ordered $n$-tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ whose sum is $k$.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, but how are there exactly $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}$ ordered $n$-tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ whose sum is $k$? I.e., how did you get $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}$ here?

Comment: In fact, I didn't. You did it in your original question ;) I'll explain. Consider again the set $(1,2,\ldots,n)$, containing $n$ elements. The term $\frac{k!}{a_1!\cdot a_2!\cdots}$ represents the number of different permutations of the unordered selection $$(\underset{a_1\text{ times}}{\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}},\underset{a_2\text{ times}}{\underbrace{2,\ldots,2}},\ldots\ldots,\underset{a_n\text{ times}}{\underbrace{n,\ldots,n}}).$$ Here $a_1+\cdots+a_n=k$ because we chose $k$ elements out of $n$.

Comment: Note that every unordered selection is of the form $$(\underset{a_1\text{ times}}{\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}},\underset{a_2\text{ times}}{\underbrace{2,\ldots,2}},\ldots\ldots,\underset{a_n\text{ times}}{\underbrace{n,\ldots,n}}).$$ We can identify such a selection with the $n$-tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. This means that the number of unordered selections of size $k$, namely $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}$, is exactly equal to the number of ordered $n$-tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ with sum $k$.

Comment: There is a more intuitive way to think of it. Suppose you wanted to divide $k$ coins in $n$ piles, such that a pile will contain a nonnegative amount of coins. You could choose an unordered tuple of $k$ piles. A pile will then receive as many coins as times the pile appeared in the tuple. Consider this equivalent combinatorial problem: There is a natural number, the sum of $k$ times $1$. (So the number equals $k$.) Then what is the number of ways to divide the ones over $n$ variables $a_1,\ldots,a_n$? Well, clearly that's simply the number of ordered $n$-tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ with sum $k$.

Comment: There is a minor mistake in my comments above. I said there are $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}$ unordered selections of size $k$ (and as many ordered $n$-tuples for which etc etc...). That should of course be $n+k-1\choose n-1$ and not $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}$. I'm sorry for not having corrected this earlier.

Comment: O sir, how amazing you are! I am obliged to have been answered by so intelligent fellow!